# w3 bootstrap carousel in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-frontend, bootstrap-carousel

I am trying to implement **Bootstrap Carousel** in **ASP.NET Web Forms**, but bootstrap carousel is not working on site. Only images are being displayed without carousel slider. I have added css and javascript files to *Site.Master* and bootstrap carousel code from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ site.

**Default.aspx** site :

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WingtipToys._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div id="MyCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel-slides-with-controls">
            <div class="carousel-item-active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="Toys%20Images/toy%20top.jpg" alt="Top" />
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="Toys%20Images/toy%20tank.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="Toys%20Images/toy%20dinosaur.jpg" />
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" area-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" area-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            <p>
                ASP.NET Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model.
            A design surface and hundreds of controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful UI-driven sites with data access.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301948">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
            <p>
                NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301949">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
            <p>
                You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301950">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

**Site.Master** Code :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WingtipToys.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
            <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the version of Bootstrap in Content/bootstrap.css? The ASP.Net Web Application (.Net Framework) template installs Bootstrap v3.4.1 by default.